# Gmail push notifications does not stop

Tags: python, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I am connecting my email to pub/sub API using "WATCH" requset. But when I going to stop notifications using below code(provided by Google) it doesn't work. I am using python client.

```
credentials = get_credentials()
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
result = service.users().stop(userId='me')
```

My references:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. was very helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
result = service.users().stop(userId='me').execute()
```

you forgot execute method, until and unless you call execute method, your statements do nothing.

Here's a small guide how to work with google apis. go to https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python and observe the code, `service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()` then go to Google API Explorer and select your service let's say Gmail API you want to use https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/gmail/v1/ , there you will see services and description,like this

> gmail.users.labels.list

here gmail is service object in your python code, and remaining were the methods, execute corresponds to execute button here in this page https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/gmail/v1/gmail.users.labels.list